# Class Template: Prevent assignment of <other> type

Tags: c++, templates, visual-c++, private

I have a `CFixedLengthString` class templates, having only data-member. The size of datamember is determined by template type argument.

```
template<size_t _Length>
class CFixedLengthString
{
private:
   char Buffer[_Length];

public:
   // Has constructors, conversion operators etc. 
   // Listing the important ones 
   operator const char*();
   operator = (const CFixedLengthString&);
   operator = (const char*);
};
```

The automatic conversions are for convenience. Example:

```
CFixedLengthString<10> buf;
buf = "SomeString";

strlen(buf);
```

But this convenience also allows following to succeed:

```
CFixedLengthString<10> buf1;
CFixedLengthString<20> buf2;
buf1 = buf2;
```

Here `buf2` is converted to `const char*` via implicit conversion operator, and `operator=` is called with `const char*`.  And thus `<20>` is converted to `<10>`.

**Important stuff here.**
For this, I wrote an assignment operator, that takes `CFixedLengthString` of different size.

```
template<size_t _TOtherSize>
void operator=(const CFixedLengthString<_TOtherSize>&);
```

And, of course, **made it private**, so that compiler error would result if `<20>` is converted to `<non-20>`. But, to my surprise, compiler doesnt complain! It allows calling this private operator!

If `<N>` is being copied to `<N>`, it calls normal assignment opeartor. If `<N>` is being copied (assigned) to `<M>` compiler calls this specialized opeartor.

But why does compiler allows calling private (as well as protected) in this scenario?? I am using VC2008 compiler. I am looking for solution for this compiler only.

For now, I have written a static-assertion within the body of this specialized function (in order to disallow such mistaken conversions).

**EDIT:**
All responses are appreciating. My only question is:

- Why specialized version, which I put in `private` area is **callable**?

We all use privates, declaration-only functions, `delete` attribute and other aspects for defensive programming. I am attempting to do the same. But compiler **allows** to call private function!

**EDIT 2:**
Sample code:

```
template<size_t SIZE>
class FixedString
{
public:
    operator const char*();
    void operator =(const char*);

    void operator =(const FixedString&);

    // Disallow
private:
    template<size_t OTHERSIZE>
    void operator=(const FixedString<OTHERSIZE>&);
};

int main()
{
    FixedString<10> buf1;
    FixedString<20> buf2;

    buf2 = buf1;   // NO ERROR!!
}
```

If I remove specialized version of `operator=`, it will still work. And I want to avoid that!

Comment: Which compiler are you using - and can you provide an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org), please?

Comment: Seems to be a bug - [gcc 4.7.2 on ideone](http://ideone.com/jC7VuO) complains about the use of private operator. I'll check it at home on VS2010 (hope I remember)

Comment: No error on VC2010 either. Errors (which is correct) on VC2012, as well as on IdeOne: http://ideone.com/RoPTLm

Comment: How about using the more general `template <class T> operator=(T const&)` ?

Comment: Seems it is a known bug: http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/649496/visual-c-doesnt-respect-the-access-modifier-for-operator-member-function-templates

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways to achieve this.

1. Your `operator const char*` may be convienient in some places, but obviously it gets triggered in some places where you don't want it to. Consider removing it, replacing it by a function akin to `std::string::c_str()` or making it `explicit` (C++11 only).
2. You could explicitly declare conversion constructors for other types that won't work - either because they are private (C++03) or deleted (C++11 only).

   ```
   template <class T> 
   CFixedLengthString& operator=(T const&) = delete;

   //or delete just other FixedLengthStrings:
   template <size_t L> // _Length is a reserved identifier, do't use it!
   CFixedLengthString& operator=(CFixedLengthString<L> const&) = delete;
   ```

Declaring operators private won't work in Visual Studio prior to VS2012, because VS does not respect private operators (known bug):
http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/649496/visual-c-doesnt-respect-the-access-modifier-for-operator-member-function-templates
Nevertheless the *linker* will complain if those operators have no implementation (they shouldn't).

Comment: I did the same thing (point 2). But compiler ALLOWS calling that private function (operator=).

Comment: It may allow calling tat private `operator=` only to those who you declared friend of `CFixedLengthString` (I would not call anyone a friend who does things to  me I don't want him to, like calling disgraced operators). And in those cases at least the linker should issue an error since you hopefully did not provide an implementation to that operator.

Comment: No friends involved in this case. Yes, linker shown errors. I will put a fully working code soon.

Comment: The only other things that has access to private members besides friends is the class itself - meaning *all* objects of the class, but only of the class, not of other instantiations of the same template.

Comment: I understand and agree with your points Arne, but they aren't relevant here.

Answer (score 1):

For your case you could remove the `operator const char*()` in favour of an accessor function such as `c_ptr()` which is a similar solution to std::string for converting to char* via c_str()

An alternative solution is to make the assignment `operator = (const char*);` private instead and define an **explicit constructor** from char* so that you can only explicitly convert between the types if needed:

```
class CFixedLengthString
{
public:
     explicit CFixedLengthString( char* str ) { *this = str );
private:
     operator = (const char*);
};

...
CFixedLengthString<10> buf1;
CFixedLengthString<20> buf2;
buf1 = CFixedLengthString<10>(buf2);
```

This current example would limit you to:

```
CFixedLengthString<10> buf1( "string" );
buf1 =  CFixedLengthString<10>("string");
```

Comment: I would not like to remove flexibility. So, `c_str` stuff is out!
The problem is not with copy constructor, but with assignment operator.
And my primary concern is with private-ness and call of that method! I need something on that persepctive, not on design perspective.

Comment: By supplying both a cast to char* and an assignment from char* conversion between types can't be easily avoided as the compiler can see this as a valid conversion. Sometimes, as with the std::string and other types the user will have to call a function. You may be able to work around it by defining a template assignment from template<int _Size2) operator = ( const CFixedLengthString<_Size2>&) and not give it a body but I cannot verify off my head if that would work at the moment as you desire.